# What to do with Passport login token once received

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication

I have made a login page for a simple exercise login app using the MERN stack and using Passport for authentication. When a user logs in the following response is returned:

```
{
“success”: true,
“token”: “Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVlYWI0NTY1NWRhZTkzMjVhNzhkZDg4YyIsIm5hbWUiOiJUZXN0b25lIFJlZ2lzdGVyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg4MjgzOTI1LCJleHAiOjE2MTk4NDA4NTF9.sU3Sj4bTg8PxNmbO2yS7qir7PGIcwtLAkpdnckffY_Y”
}
```

Question - I am wondering what I’m supposed to do with the token that is returned when designing my React frontend UI that will return any user data in my MongoDB database.

Answer (score 0):

The token value should be used to authorize users by including it each request in the header as the value to the `authorization` key.